# Is it possible to implement Cloud Recording in Flutter

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Is it possible to implement Cloud Recording in Flutter using https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine this dependency?
I have checked the https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms#start But it's not helpful for Flutter.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the cloud recording provided SDK provided by Agora but you will need to create your own server to record a particular stream. You can have a look at the sample code given here: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording